# Mobile First Platform Failed to create an ILMT record

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My current MFP 7.1 setup is using relational database for WL and WLADMIN database.  This a brand new setup, clean DB, clean server (linux), etc...

When I start my MFP server up, I am getting the following:

> Jul 28, 2016 2:28:32 PM com.worklight.core.ilmt.WorklightILMTLogger
>   dumpLicense INFO: FWLSE0277I: Creating an ILMT record in the file
>   '/app/user/catalina_base/logs/16e25eeec7bed9508cb5168efcaeaa4c.slmtag'.
>   Jul 28, 2016 2:28:32 PM com.worklight.core.ilmt.WorklightILMTLogger
>   dumpLicense SEVERE: FWLSE0367E: Missing License Report data. Failed to
>   create an ILMT record.

Does anyone from Mobile First Platform support know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to a problem in writing this ILMT file, but it doesn't affect any behavior other than ILMT.
If you don't need the ILMT, you can ignore it.